# For-loop to find values falling into a specified interval in Matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix, indexing, intervals

In Matlab I have a matrix `pvals` where `size(pvals) = 210 x 210`.

I want to "search" the matrix such that if any value in `pvals` is such that

`pvals < 2.7613 or pvals > 0.3621405`

Then I want another matrix `VALS` to record that entry as `0`. So that in the end I end up with this matrix `VALS` which is the same size as `pvals` but is filled with `0's` and `1's` based on whether the corresponding value in pvals fell into the interval I have specified or outside.

I have tried the following for-loop

```
for i=1:size(pvals,1)
        if pvals(i) < 2.7613 && pvals(i) > 0.3621405
            VALS(i) = 0;
        else VALS(i) = 1;
        end
end
```

But this creates a `1x210` matrix `VALS` instead of `210x210`, I'm guessing because I am just looping over it once in `i=1:size(pvals,1)`??

Would anyone be able to help?

Thanks

Comment: To fix your code, start by defining `VALS = zeros(size(pvals));` and change the line `for i=1:size(pvals,1)` to `for i=1:numel(pvals)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to use loops for this in Matlab:

```
VALS = ~(pvals < 2.7613 | pvals > 0.3621405);
```

By the way, to fix your loop (and for every loop you ever make in Matlab) you should pre-allocate memory by just adding the line

```
VALS = zeros(size(pvals));
```

before you loop.

Comment: Actually I want `0.3621405 < p < 2.7613` so I have changed it to `VALS = ~(pvals < 2.7613 & pvals > 0.3621405)` which gives me what I want so thanks!!

Comment: And suppose if I didn't 0's and 1's... and that if the value fell into that interval it would get value 0 otherwise it would retain the entry in `pvals` instead of getting 1

Comment: `VALS = ~(pvals < 2.7613 | pvals > 0.3621405).*pvals`

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in one line i matlab:

```
VALS = pvals >= 2.7613 | pvals <= 0.3621405;
```